# telethon database locked, i need optimization

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, telethon

The database is locked, can't even start the program

how to make it so that a new session is not created, but connects to the old session?
I got banned because of too many connections. I don't know what to do.

```
import logging
import os
import download
import yt_dlp
import list
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import time
load_dotenv()
chats = list.chats
api_id = os.getenv("api_id")
api_hash = os.getenv("api_hash")
logging.basicConfig(
    format="[%(levelname) 5s/%(asctime)s] %(name)s: %(message)s", level=logging.WARNING
)

def downloadvideo(link):
    with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL() as ydl:
        ydl.download(link)


from telethon import TelegramClient, events
client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(
    events.NewMessage(
        chats=chats,
        pattern=r"(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be|tiktok\.com)",
    )
)
async def my_event_handler(event):
    if event.chat_id in chats:
        message_id = event.id
        video = download.downloadvideo(event.message.message)
        message = f"[link]({event.message.message})"
        await client.send_file(
            -1001673012624,
            reply_to=message_id,
            file="telegramvideo.mp4",
            video_note=True,
            caption=message,
        )
        os.remove("telegramvideo.mp4")

phone = os.getenv("phone")
# -1001919227306 maratozpanov
client.start(phone=phone)
```

Delete session file. I thought it would work after I deleted it.

Comment: any error you are getting?

Comment: `sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked`
and  now i get banned :(`telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.FloodWaitError: A wait of 15741 seconds is required (caused by SendCodeRequest)`

Comment: `UserWarning: the session already had an authorized user so it did not login to the user account using the provided phone (it may not be using the user you expect)
  warnings.warn(`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are posting a lot of different problems in a different question.

> how to make it so that a new session is not created, but connects to the old session?

This is done by simply using the same session name as the first parameter to the `TelegramClient` constructor.

> I got banned because of too many connections

[Telegram decides when the bans occur](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/824). This is not something the library can help with. VoIP numbers in particular are very prone to being banned.

> ```py
> with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL() ...
> ```

I'm not familiar with `yt_dlp`, but if the library is threaded, be mindful that Telethon uses `asyncio`. If the `asyncio` event loop cannot run (because the thread is blocked), things may misbehave.

I recommend you read the `asyncio` documentation and learn about running blocking functions in executors.

> `sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked`

This likely means the session file is being used by multiple processes. Make sure there is only one process accessing the same session file at a time. Use multiple sessions if you need multiple concurrent processes.

> telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.FloodWaitError

This means you've attempted to make that request far too many times and Telegram is rate-limitting you. You can only wait, and avoid making that request so often (likely related to the problems you have reusing sessions, addressed in other points).

> `UserWarning: the session already had an authorized user so it did not login to the user account using the provided phone (it may not be using the user you expect)`

This means the session you are trying to reuse was already logged-in previously, but now, you've provided a different phone. So the library warns you that it ignored the new phone because the account was already logged-in.